# React - Login Error from PHP not displaying

Tags: reactjs, forms, authentication

I am trying to display an error text message fetched from a PHP. I see from debugging that the message is returned correctly in the `responseJson.message` object but I'm not able to find out whether the state is updating it or why it is not rendering properly in the HTML since the page reloads itself and the input fields are emptied right after the `this.setState({ error: responseJson.message })` instruction.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { PostData } from '../../modules/PostData';

class LoginForm extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            error: "",
            username: "",
            password: ""
        }
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    }

    onSubmit() {
        this.setState({ error: "" })
        PostData('login', this.state).then((responseJson) => {
            if (responseJson.message === "login success") {
                sessionStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(responseJson));
                document.location.href = `/home`
            } else {
                console.log(this.state.error)
                this.setState({ error: responseJson.message })
            }
        })
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label><br />
                    <input name="username" component="input" type="text" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label><br />
                    <input name="password" component="input" type="password" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit">Login</button>
                </div>
                <div name="error" className='error' component="input" type="text" value={this.state.error}></div>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default LoginForm
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `component, value, type` attributes in div tag. In your case you should use:

```
<div name="error" className='error'>{this.state.error}</div>
```

or

```
<input name="error" className='error' component="input" type="text" value={this.state.error}></input>
```

Comment: That was it @Mozgovoy Artem! Thanks! The page still reloads by itself right after displaying (now correctly) the error message. Any idea why this is?

Comment: You submitting from and that causes calling url- "yourSiteBaseUrl + formParams", if dont wanna use actual form submit you can call `onSubmit(event) {event.preventDefault();` before your code

Comment: there is actually many ways to avoid form submit: you can change button type:
`<button type="button" onClick={this.submitForm}>Login</button>` and remove submit handler from `<form/>`

Comment: Obliviously I am lacking some basic React concepts. That worked like a charm, I cannot thank you enough!

Comment: Its more like html/js basics. For start i would recommend https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms

Upvotes and marking as accepted answer will be enough gratitude for stackoverflow)